# Merge PDF files with PHP into single file

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, tcpdf, fpdi

If i have some `PDF` files, each has one page and i would like to `merge` all files into on single file using `PHP`

I have read dozens of questions here about same but most of all are out of date or no longer working since for `PHP version >= 7.0`

One of the solutions was to use [PDFMerger](https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger) and here is my code

```
require_once ('PDFMerger.php');

use PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('books/1.pdf');
$pdf->addPDF('books/2.pdf');

$pdf->merge('download','books/merged.pdf');
```

but if simply gives blank page and no file is created and same to this library [PDFMerger](https://github.com/libremente/PDFMerger)

**UPDATE1**! wihtout namespace use `PDFMerger\PDFMerger;` iam getting this error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PDFMerger" not found in mypath\sample.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in mypath\sample.php on line 4
```

so is there any way that is still working to merger PDF files without have to care how such file are created.

NOTE! I can not use `shell_exec` since files are on shared hosting

Comment: Can you try removing the file path? As you do not need to give a file path for browser, string, or download options - just the name is needed. Check [here](https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger/blob/master/sample.php#L12)

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of time , i decide to shift back to a lower PHP version `7.1` rather than `8.0` and everything goes fine though